# Combine Cocoa App and Commandline Tool into one App Bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode5

How may I combine a Commandline Tool and a Cocoa Application into one App using XCode?

Finally I need to show the output of the Commandline Tool (stdout and stderr) to a NSTextBox.

Comment: At the moment I manually copy the commandline tool into the Application Bundle. Is there a way let this XCode manage automatically? So that a build of the App will add both into the bundle?

Comment: You have another project that builds the binary? Or it's a static binary? You have a copy bundle resources build phase?

Comment: Yes. I currently have two seperate projects. One for the commandline tool (static binary), the other containing the Cocoa App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the binary project (or add) as a dependency of the main project. This means that it will always be built before the main projects.

Next add a copy bundle resources build phase (or use an existing one) and drag the binary product from the binary project in. This will copy the resulting binary from the first build into the bundle created by the second build.

To run the binary you need to get its path using `NSBundle` and then [run it using `NSTask`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976289/executing-shell-commands-with-nstask-objective-c-cocoa).