# NSTask not working as expected / hoped for

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminal, nstask

get_iplayer allows user to download files from the BBC iPlayer service. It is awesome, they both are.

I'm attempting to run a get_iplayer command from within Xcode using NSTask:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/users/myuser/documents/get_iplayer_install/get_iplayer"];
NSArray *args = @[@"--type=radio",@"--pid",  @"--modes=flashaacstd,rtspaaclow",  @"b006tnvx"];
[task setArguments:args];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

This is intended to do the same job as when I run this from terminal:

```
get_iplayer --type=radio --pid b006tnvx
```

However, it produces this output:

```
get_iplayer v2.90, Copyright (C) 2008-2010 Phil Lewis
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details use --warranty.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain
conditions; use --conditions for details.

WARNING: rdf URL contained no data
WARNING: PID URL contained no RDF data. Trying to record PID directly.
INFO: Trying pid: --modes=flashaaclow using type: radio
INFO: Trying to stream pid using type radio
INFO: pid not found in radio cache
Matches:

INFO: 1 Matching Programmes

ERROR: Failed to get version pid metadata from iplayer site

WARNING: rdf URL contained no data
WARNING: PID URL contained no RDF data. Trying to record PID directly.
INFO: Trying pid: flashaacstd using type: radio
INFO: Trying to stream pid using type radio
INFO: pid not found in radio cache
Matches:

INFO: 1 Matching Programmes

ERROR: Failed to get version pid metadata from iplayer site

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Whereas it ought to produce something *like* this:

[image]

I don't think this is a get_iplayer question, it's my lack of understanding about NSTask and probably about how unix works.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Andy

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976289/executing-shell-commands-with-nstask-objective-c-cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are in the wrong order. You've got the --modes argument and value in between the --pid argument in value.

The output says as much by saying it can't find a pid with the name of the name of --modes=flashaaclow